# sending the project to an existing repo

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to send a project to an existing private repository on github. I don't see an option in Visual Studio 2022 to send to an existing repo, just to create a new one. Maybe I'm looking wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In short, create a new repository in VS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-create-repository?view=vs-2022

Next copy/move existing solution to folder you selected on creating repo step.Now commit and push the changes to your existing repo.

You can also configure .gitignore to not push build files (.exe ect.). Easy way is to use some existing ignore templates for .Net projects.

Answer (score 0):

Since the remote repository is already existant, you need to clone it first, then make the necessary modifications and commit.

Answer (score 0):

Even easier, I found I could clone the repo to my computer, take the .git folder from the root directory, put it at the root directory of the project I want to push, restart visual studio and I could immediately commit all my changes!